# .Net Regex to highlight keywords including special characters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Keywords highlighters that are available on the internet do not highlight special characters. 
e.g. http://sites.google.com/site/yewiki/aspnet/highlighting-multiple-search-keywords-in-aspnet

How can I make them hightlight any characters. e.g. C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the example is pretty much just taking the search string as the Regex and replacing the spaces with the or operator(|). Special characters entered will be misinterpreted as Regex operators. Much like the code exaple does a `.Replace(" ", "|")` , you can do a series of replaces like `.Replace("@", "\@")` to make sure the specials are escaped in the Regex and not interpreted as there special meaning.
I'm not sure exactly what you are after, but you could also just append the "\@" or whatever specials you are looking for to the Regex expression. I assume if you are doing a C++ like code highlighter your Regex will be a constant, and not a typed in search string like the example you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to get clear what you mean by "highlight any characters".

Do you want to highlight all characters that aren't letters or numbers?  Or do you want in the case of `C++` to highlight the whole word?

Once you've got it straight, you can use a regex table [like this one](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) to work out a suitable regex for matching.

Or better still you can re-use something like [syntax-highlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter) or [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

There's also a [well-written article](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/syntax-highlighting-stackoverflow-google-prettify) on codingthewheel.com that may be helpful to you.